# Windows freezes and crashes

Tags: freeze, crash, shutdown, reboot

So, I was playing something with my friends on discord and out of the blue the screen freezes, but I can still hear the sounds, my friend's voices and the game and not more than 5 seconds later, the screen goes black for 1 second and the computer restarts as if I pressed the restart button.

I tried playing it again under the same circumstances, and the it happen exactly the same way. But then, the third time, not giving me even time to open the game again, it just froze and stayed that way, so I had to manually restart it.

The fourth time, it also went a little different. This time it had been about 1hour since the last freeze, and there I was playing the game and out of the blue the mouse stopped working, but the keyboard remained functional, as I was able to press esc to pause it, but again, 5 seconds later, screen turns black and restarts.

The fifth time, it happened while I was watching Netflix and not even touching the keyboard/mouse.

This whole series of events happened within the period of a day.

-Windows 10
-GeForce GTX 970
-2x 8GB corsair RAM
-Intel Core i3 3570k
-AsRock Z77 Extreme

I don't know if it could be related to the issue, but over the past 2 years or so, there has been occurring another problem, but this one rarely occurs.

On turning the pc on, It would emit 4 beeps, before even showing something on screen and shut down, then automatically turns on, and repeat and so on. The "solution" I found to this was opening it up, removing the RAM cards and putting them back on, sometimes on other slots and turning It back on, and sometimes it would work, sometimes it wouldn't, so I'd do it all over again ultil it worked. Also tried borrowing a 4 x 4GB RAM from my friend, but the problem would remain, maybe even worse.

This event could also happen out of nowhere while using the pc, as it would shutdown instantly and then start the process described above.

Edit1: so it happened that I was monitoring the task manager when it froze and restarted, recently, and I noticed that the cpu usage was pretty close to 100% and it cause the computer to lag for about 5 seconds before restarting

Comment: So many possibilities... RAM, graphics, etc.

Comment: We need the stop code, that Windows told you, when it crashed.

Comment: @BadSnowflake where would I get this code?

Comment: Press `Windows+R`, type `eventvwr.msc` and look for errors. Look in Windows Logs -> System. There should be several errors, one being your bluescreen.

Comment: So, there are 2 red errors here:
One being a 'Critial', which has the following keywords (70368744177664),(2) and a task category (63) and event id 41, source: Kernel-Power

Comment: @BadSnowflake the other error, I think is just saying that it shut down unexpectedly, as it has no keywords